# How to feed in and retrieve state of LSTM in tensorflow C/ C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'd like to build and train a multi-layer LSTM model (stateIsTuple=True) in python, and then load and use it in C++. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to feed and fetch states in C++, mainly because I don't have string names which I can reference.

E.g. I put the initial state in a named scope such as

```
    with tf.name_scope('rnn_input_state'):
        self.initial_state = cell.zero_state(args.batch_size, tf.float32)
```

and this appears in the graph as below, but how can I feed to these in C++?

[image]

Also, how can I fetch the current state in C++? I tried the graph construction code below in python but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do, because last_state should be a tuple of tensors, not a single tensor (though I can see that the last_state node in tensorboard is 2x2x50x128, which sounds like it just concatenated the states as I have 2 layers, 128 rnn size, 50 mini batch size, and lstm cell - with 2 state vectors).

```
    with tf.name_scope('outputs'):
        outputs, last_state = legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder(inputs, self.initial_state, cell, loop_function=loop if infer else None)
        output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(outputs, 1), [-1, args.rnn_size], name='output')
```

and this is what it looks like in tensorboard

[image]

Should I concat and split the state tensors so there is only ever one state tensor going in and out? Or is there a better way?

P.S. Ideally the solution won't involve hard-coding the number of layers (or rnn size). So I can just have four strings input_node_name, output_node_name, input_state_name, output_state_name, and the rest is derived from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to do this by manually concatenating the state into a single tensor. I'm not sure if this is wise, since this is how tensorflow *used* to handle states, but is now deprecating that and switching to tuple states. Instead of setting state_is_tuple=False and risking my code being obsolete soon, I've added extra ops to manually stack and unstack the states to and from a single tensor. Saying that, it works fine both in python and C++.

The key code is:

```
# setting up
zero_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
state_in = tf.identity(zero_state, name='state_in')         

# based on https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/using-the-tensorflow-multilayered-lstm-api-f6e7da7bbe40#.zhg4zwteg
state_per_layer_list = tf.unstack(state_in, axis=0)
state_in_tuple = tuple(
    # TODO make this not hard-coded to LSTM
    [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(state_per_layer_list[idx][0], state_per_layer_list[idx][1])
    for idx in range(num_layers)]
)

outputs, state_out_tuple = legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder(inputs, state_in_tuple, cell, loop_function=loop if infer else None)
state_out = tf.identity(state_out_tuple, name='state_out')

# running (training or inference)
state = sess.run('state_in:0') # zero state

loop:
    feed = {'data_in:0': x, 'state_in:0': state}
    [y, state] = sess.run(['data_out:0', 'state_out:0'], feed)
```

Here is the full code if anyone needs it
https://github.com/memo/char-rnn-tensorflow